# nuxt.js with paper.js is breaking nuxt-links

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, paperjs

I am trying to get paper js running with nuxt.js -- and it is working. But as soon as I start the `paper.install(window)` command all nuxt-links won't work anymore.

I am seeing this error in the console:

```
nuxt-link.client.js?4e55:89 Uncaught TypeError: Components[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
    at VueComponent.prefetchLink (nuxt-link.client.js?4e55:89)
    at eval (nuxt-link.client.js?4e55:23)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at IntersectionObserver.observer (nuxt-link.client.js?4e55:19)
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: Avoid running a global scope with `paper.install(window);` and it will work.

Comment: In my humble opinion, your answer seems like a comment. any explanation ? any reason? any clarity ?

Comment: I do not know why the global scope of paper causes problems with nuxt-links. But this is still the workaround ...